# Error when trying to add reference to "Azure.Communication.Sms" from Azure Function script

Tags: azure-functions, azure-communication-services

With a C# version 6 (and 3.1) csx Azure Function script, I cannot add a reference:

#r "Azure.Communication.Sms"

I get an error:

error CS0006: Metadata file 'Azure.Communication.Sms' could not be found

The same code referencing same library in a .net 6 console app locally works using this same nuget package.

Here is the code in question that I cannot use SmsClient because the reference cannot be added:

```
#r "Azure.Communication.Sms"
#r "Azure.Messaging.EventGrid"
#r "System.Text.Json"
#r "System.Memory.Data"

using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid;
using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.SystemEvents;
using System.Text.Json;

using Azure;
using Azure.Communication;
using Azure.Communication.Sms;


public static void Run(EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.EventType.ToString());

    if (eventGridEvent.EventType == "Microsoft.Communication.SMSReceived")
    {
        var msg = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.SystemEvents.AcsSmsReceivedEventData>(eventGridEvent.Data);

        log.LogInformation(msg.Message);

        // now send out to others


        string connectionString = "ENTER CONNECTION STRING HERE";

        SmsClient smsClient = new SmsClient(connectionString);

        // ...
    }


}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

*Create a new Azure function App with 3.1 or 6.0*

[image]
[image]

*Install Azure.Communication.Sms from NuGet*

[image]

*Create a script file using the below steps.*

1. *Add a new item to the project and choose a text file. And add the text file to the project.*

[image]

2. *Rename the text file extension with .csx, then a script file is created.*

[image]

3. *Add the code which you want to RUN, it will run without any errors.*

[image]

*Able to build and run the code without any errors*

[image]

*Verified in Azure portal and also able to run the script without any errors*
[image]

*Logs*
[image]

Comment: We are using portal.azure.com -> Create a Resource -> Function App -> Code, .NET, 6, Windows, Serverless ->Create a Function -> Template - Azure Event Grid Trigger (develop in portal) -> Code and Test -> Paste the example -> Save  (But open a monitor/logs first so you see the errors).  Then you will see the error.  As I said, I can run in VS locally with no issues.

Comment: @user1867382, You can find the last two azure screenshots in which there is no error, after using the same code.